# Is there a performance difference between JQuery Map and JSknockout ko.utils.arrayMap?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working with JSKnockout for a while and the way i used to map the observable array is the following

```
model.Entries($.map(data.Benefits, function (e, i) { return new BenefitEntry(e.Name, e.ID); }));
```

So i know we have a Util functionality with Knockout which is

```
model.Entries(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Benefits, function(item) {
    return new BenefitEntry(item.Name, item.ID)
}));
```

is there going to be any difference using the util one .. I am trying to understand if there is a difference or it is the same thing" for performance or any other aspect that i might missed here "

Comment: The performance ship has pretty much sailed when using frameworks like knockout.

Comment: It looks like this is already a test case on jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/knockout-map-vs-jquery-map Just click the "Run Tests" button. Short version: jQuery map is slower. But using a standard for loop is fastest. (in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 32-bit on Windows 8 64-bit)

Comment: You should move code out of tests behind static functions, otherwise you are just testing cold code and therefore the results don't necessarily reflect reality.

Comment: Off topic because: per @ArrayKnight, this [jsperf test case](http://jsperf.com/knockout-map-vs-jquery-map) already exists.

Comment: Thanks guys i am trying to improve the quality of the it since i start have cases where i need to bind huge data and in some cases i have issues with performance

Comment: @ArrayKnight,  is that test applied on normal array or ran observable array .. I am interested to see the difference applied on an observable  array!